# The page cannot be displayed - Refresh Page

Tags: c#, selenium

sometimes, when navigating to a url, I'm getting an error:

> The page cannot be displayed

I have tried to use `_driver.Navigate().Refresh`
but nothing happens.

I have also tried using the following:

```
 try
 {
     _webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(FinalLinkRegistration);
 }
 catch
 {
     Actions actions = new Actions(_webdriverIE);
     actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.F5).Perform();
 }
```

The page remains with

> The page cannot be displayed

until it reaches timeout configured.

In addition, I assume that even if I'll success refreshing the page, I'll have to do something else in order to make elements active again(clickable,visible etc..)?

Comment: is it just automation or manually also you are observing such behavior?

Comment: Just automation unfortunately

Comment: is it http or https site? is it happening with some specific browser only or all the browsers?

Comment: Https and happens both with IE and Chrome. Didn't check Safari, Firefox

Comment: is SSL certificate valid?

Comment: Yes sure. Sorry for that. I didn't mention it happens sometimes and sometimes it works good. It is not stable

Comment: Ohh actually I did mention. At the beginning of my post

Comment: Any of those options should work so the problem isn't the code. It could be something else in your test infrastructure. Are you using selenium grid? What version of selenium? Is the site remote? Is it public? Is the problem with one url, or all? Can you automate other sites? Have you had a look at the network traffic? What HTTP status is associated with the error?

Comment: yes, I'm using selenium grid.the problem is with specific URL I'm taking from an email as a link and navigating to it. the problem is that sometimes it works and sometimes it isn't. unstable.  havn't look the network traffic. what should I expect?

Comment: stupid question: are there special characters in the URL sometimes? or do you have access to the server logs to see if a proper request was sent?

Comment: yes,URL has some special characters. unfortunately, I don't have any access to verify a proper request was sent

Comment: Look for the HTTP status of failed requests. When the page can't be displayed open the developer tools in the browser and refresh manually. The HTTP status should give more info about why the page can't be displayed. E.g., if special characters in the URL cause problems on the server you might see a 500 error.

Comment: I'd try to parse the URL out each time and save in text so you can see if the times it fails there are some differences than in the times it succeeds.  I'd think it's supposed to be the same each time.  Also can you tell us more about what the page is doing when it loads?  Perhaps you are sometimes attempting to interact before the page loads and it's causing selenium to lose the page.  I have hit that sometimes and it's usually like partial loading pages that then force some refresh or after load script and it interrupts selenium and focus is lost.  Visually it's fine, just not for automation

Comment: Are you able to access the url directly in your local browser?